# Maximum Subset Sum with Pairwise Constraints

Tags: algorithms, approximation, clique, subset-sum

(*Note*: I am posting after reading some possibly related posts because I could not find a fitting solution.)

Given some finite set of nodes $S$, where each node $s_i \in S$ has a value $val(s_i) \in [0,1]$ and moreover has a pairwise similarity value to each other node, i.e $sim(s_i, s_j) \in [0,1]$, I want to find the maximal sum subset $C \subset S$ of $k$ many nodes  such that the pairwise similarity of all pairs $sim(c_i, c_j) > T$ is larger than some threshold.

The best complexity I could come up with is exponential with a backtracking approach.
I am wondering if there is a more efficient solution or any approximate solutions. For context, I am hoping to implement and run this algorithm.

Comment: The problem is equivalent to [maximum weighted clique problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#:~:text=In%20the%20weighted%20maximum%20clique,which%20all%20weights%20are%20equal.) which is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard. You can find a lot of literature on it.